# Using Probit for Prediction - What to do about variance in the estimates?

Tags: variance, prediction, probit

Suppose I am estimating the following model:

$Pr(Y=1|X) = \Phi(X'\beta + \epsilon)$

where $X = [X_1,X_2]$.

Further suppose I end up with estimates for $X_1$ and $X_2$ of $\beta_1 = \beta_2 = \beta$.  Despite equivalent effect magnitudes, let's say the variance in these estimates is quite different.  The variance in $\beta_1$ is quite small ($z$-score >> 1.96), so the effect is clear.  The variance in $\beta_2$, by contrast, covers up the estimate entirely ($z$-score << 1.96).

Here's the rub.  I want to use my estimates to predict the likelihood that a given record will exhibit $Y=1$.  The typical `predict()` methods (or advocated manual approaches with which I am familiar) pitch the following solution:

$p_i = F(X_i'\beta)$

where $X_i = [x_{i,1},x_{i,2}]$ and $F()$ is a normal CDF.

It seems to me that if the estimate of $X_2$'s effect is indistinguishable from zero, it should not impact the probability estimate with the same force as the clear signal from the estimate of $X_1$'s effect.  However, if we were to weight the parameter estimates in a manner commensurate with each estimate's contribution to total variance in all estimated parameters, it seems like the effect would be equivalent to using a different location in the estimate's distribution for the affected variables.  (Instead of using $E[\beta]$, we'd be using a value that might sit at perhaps the 20th percentile location in the distribution of $\beta$.) So, moving away from central tendencies also seems problematic.

How might one resolve this tension?  Perhaps just as importantly, is it worth resolving, or is it much ado about nothing?

Comment: The easiest way out is, maybe, to use a bayesian approach and then find (by simulation) the posterior distribution of $P(Y=1 | x)$ (for varios relevant $x$).

Comment: So, simulate draws from the distributions of $\beta$ for each variable?  I like where your head is at, but it seems to me the simulation count requirement would increase quickly with the number of variables to give sufficient coverage of the joint distributions of $\beta = [\beta_1,...,\beta_k]$.  I have 34 (years) $\times$ 4 (subpopulations) = 136 prediction calculations to run on sets with roughly 50,000 observations.  Each spec has about 70 variables, so this solution seems to require a lot of cycles.

Comment: You could do it within an mcmc algorithm ... should be doable. Especially when predicted probabilities are close to zero or one, uncertainty in the betas can be important, the posterior intervals of the $P(Y=1)$ can be very asymmetric.